# PHP - Using strtotime with a UK date format (dd-mm-yy)

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Quite simply in PHP I have a date of 8th January 2011, in the format 08-01-11 - when I run this into strtotime and convert it back into a different date format, it reverts back to 1st August 2011 - not ideal!

Is there any easy way around this, rather than having to place everything into different arrays/variables and back again?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`strtotime()` [works with US dates only](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> The function expects to be given a string containing a US English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp.

You would have to either rearrange the date format or use [`date_parse_from_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) (PHP 5.3+) to parse the UK style string.

Comment: @Nick I see! Then a `explode("-", $date);` and rearranging the array may be the best solution.

Answer (score 31):

The perfect solution would be for the US to use the correct date format in the first place... ;0)

I do this to get around it:

```
$date = "31/12/2012";
$bits = explode('/',$date);
$date = $bits[1].'/'.$bits[0].'/'.$bits[2];
```

`$date` is now `strtotime`able

Comment: This does work, but the answer from gregmacoy achieves the same and is much simpler.

Answer (score 19):

From the PHP manual:

> "Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible."

I replaced slashes with dashes and then strtotime worked as expected for UK dates.

Comment: Perfect answer.