# Format date dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a form within which a date is input in UK format, and I need to convert it to

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

e.g. a date entered is: `31/03/2013` which I want to convert to `'2013-03-31'` for database insert.

I'm using the following which bizarrely works only sometimes:

```
$dateInput = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
$show_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateInput));
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why are you escaping the date value.... does it actually serve any purpose at all?

Comment: When is this not working properly? Also, escaping doesn't seem a good idea (or at least it seems useless if the date format is correct). Maybe you should consider using a regex to check the initial format.

Comment: @Darren the reason this doesn't work sometimes is because PHP expects the date to be in US format. You have to re-arrange it before handing it over to `strtotime()`, if at all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163641/php-using-strtotime-with-a-uk-date-format-dd-mm-yy

Comment: @Uby I escape everything so some **** doesnt try injecting

Comment: @Darren - redundant in this case as you're converting the string to a datetime serialization and then back again - you have control... and if you think something could be injected, then escape doesn't do quite what you think

Comment: you do not you use the checkdate function to validate the Date

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks for explaining that, I get it now. Good to know, appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might want to use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$show_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dateInput)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: The idea is good, but `date_parse_from_format` returns `array` while `date` accepts `int` as second input.

Comment: Oh sorry you already edited it.

Comment: @Voitcus Yeah, I just noticed after posting the answer

Comment: Note (and this is a big note): PHP 5.3.0 and greater only!

Comment: @Tushar that's ok, it's 2018 now :)

Answer (score 11):

try it.

```
$dateInput = explode('/','31/03/2013');
$ukDate = $dateInput[2].'-'.$dateInput[1].'-'.$dateInput[0];
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I did a different one with preg_replace (one-line).

Comment: Also you can do this without any functions like explode using string array notation.

Answer (score 3):

> following which bizarrely works only sometimes:

```
$show_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateInput));
```

this is no other shorter way to do it.... and i am using this all my life.. havn't notice any bizzare things going on with it till now.. check if there is some other things that is messing up

otherway to do it is

```
$timestamp = strtotime(str_replace('/', '.', $dateInput));
$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

Comment: With slashes, strtotime() expects a US-format date, not a UK-format date, which is why it would screw up for some values.

Comment: I always wonder if 02/03/04 is 2nd March of 2004, 4th March of 2002, 3rd February of 2004 or... I think PHP always takes the last possibility, so this is not what is given in the input.

Comment: @Tushar Thanks, that makes sense when I look at the dates it was screwing up.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$dte  = '28/03/2013';
$dt   = new DateTime();
$date = $dt->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dte);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Output: `2013-03-28`

Comment: best answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.3 and up

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat.](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) It allows you to specify an exact mask - using the date() syntax - to parse incoming string dates with.

PHP 5.2 and lower

You will have to parse the elements (year, month, day, hour, minute, second) manually using substr() and hand the results to [mktime()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) that will build you a timestamp.

Comment: He's already using `strtotime()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$date_array = explode("/",$your_date); // split the array
$var_day = $date_array[0]; //day seqment
$var_month = $date_array[1]; //month segment
$var_year = $date_array[2]; //year segment
echo $new_date_format = "$var_year-$var_day-$var_month"; // join them  together
```

This will work

Answer (score 0):

Couple of alternate methods. Both output 2013-03-31:

Method 1 - "Look ma, no functions"

```
<?php
    $in = '31/03/2013';
    echo $in[6].$in[7].$in[8].$in[9].'-'.$in[3].$in[4].'-'.$in[0].$in[1];
    ?>
```

Method 2 - regex

```
<?php
    echo ($output = preg_replace('!^([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})$!',"$3-$2-$1",$input));
?>
```