# subtract two dates in php

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP calculate age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776682/php-calculate-age)

I'm trying to subtract the years and check the user's age. I keep getting 1969 for $user_birth, which I think the raw date can't be parsed.

```
$raw_birth = "01-19-1980";
$user_birth = date("Y", strtotime($raw_birth));
$today_date = date("Y", time());

echo $raw_birth."<br />".$today_date."<br />".$user_birth."<br />";
echo $today_date-$user_birth;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That Q was very helpful. Thanks! :)

Comment: You can get 2 rep for each answer you accept.

Comment: A tick appears left to each answer. Just click on it to answer the best answer to any of your other questions. This question has no answers yet, only comments.

Comment: Watch out for for Lyme disease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$year="1997";
$month="01";
$day="24";

$age=date("Y");
$age-= $year;
if(($month>=date("m")) && ($day>date("d"))) {
    $age--;
}
```

This code calculates an accurate age of an user.