# Unix time stamp to age in php

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I have this line of code.
obviously it just grabs the date of birth per user and put it in the view where
I want it.
The problem is that it shows it in a UNIX timestamp.
Is there an easy way to adjust the line so the outcome will be the age of the user?

```
<dl class="clearfix bg-lightgrey user-dash-dl tc">
<dd class="fl br-1 lh36" style="width:72px">
<p class="f11 ff-l lh12 pt33">Age</p>
<p class="ff-m f12"><?= $user_info['date_of_birth']?></p> </dd> </dl>
```

above you see the code.
Thanks:)

Comment: [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: Hope this helps, you can check the answer of Dini88 in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186811/calculating-age-from-date-of-birth-in-php

Comment: Try this `<p class="ff-m f12"><?= date('Y') - date('Y', $user_info['date_of_birth']) ?></p> </dd> </dl>`

Comment: @yowza Your solution does not consider the days. As the birthday of the user has been, there should be a year be added.

Comment: try this
<?= (time() - $user_info['date_of_birth']) /(365*60*60*24) ?>

Comment: @Marten thanks for pointing it out what I missed!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PHP `date()` function. It formats your timestamp into a human readable format. See for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp

```
<dl class="clearfix bg-lightgrey user-dash-dl tc">
<dd class="fl br-1 lh36" style="width:72px">
<p class="f11 ff-l lh12 pt33">Age</p>
<p class="ff-m f12"><?= date('Y-m-d', $user_info['date_of_birth']) ?></p> </dd> </dl>
```

For calculating the number of years since a specific date, use this:

```
echo date_diff(date_create(date('Y-m-d', timestamp)), date_create('today'))->y;
```

So, in your situation it should be:

```
echo date_diff(date_create(date('Y-m-d', $user_info['date_of_birth'])), date_create('today'))->y;
```

Comment: He want age of user in years/days not a date of birth

Comment: Can you tell me how to put it in the code above?