# Convert user date of birth html input to age in php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get the date from the date-time-picker name="dob" into the php but it only post 2017 in the database user_age column. However, if I assigned $dob manually to $dob = '10/09/1988' it works.

```
<div class="form-group date-time-picker label-floating is-empty">
 <label class="control-label">Birthday</label>
 <input name="datetimepicker">
</div>
```

And here is the php

```
<?php
 $dob = $_GET['datetimepicker'];
 $dob = explode("/", $dob);
 $agv = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $dob[0], $dob[1], $dob[2]))) > 
 date("md") ? ((date("Y") - $dob[2]) -1) : (date("Y") - $dob[2]));

 $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $agv);
?>
```

Comment: what format is the date being submitted in from the datepicker? dd/mm/yyyy? mm/dd/yyyy? Something else? How are you verifying in the server that the date format was valid and expected?

Comment: according to the js of the datetimepicker, the format is MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: What are the exact contents of `$_GET['dob']`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating age from date of birth in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186811/calculating-age-from-date-of-birth-in-php)

Comment: @jeroen It should pull the value of a datetimepicker inside the div above with format MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: I don't really care what it should do, I want to know what it contains exactly.

Comment: @FMeshreky, should do, or actually does do? Big difference. You can test that pretty straightforwardly

Comment: jcorry's answer is correct assuming you have a valid date in mm/dd/yyyy format (or any other other formats deemed acceptable in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: you have two `name` attributes for you input. The `datetimepicker` one probably should go somewhere else, maybe `type` (as `type="date"`) or `class`

Comment: @jeroen what I mean is it refers to the <input> with name="dob" value and pulls the data inserted by the user. Sorry if I didn't understand the purpose of your comment.

Comment: You have 1 input field. It has 2 'name' attributes. That's not legal HTML. No wonder PHP has no idea what is in $_GET['dob'].

Comment: @KarstenKoop Thanks for the note I changed it to id

Comment: @jcorry I changed it and now it is referring to name="datetimepicker' but I've got the same post to the database as 2017 with my code and 00 with your code below

Comment: Because now the value is in $_GET[‘datetimepicker’]

Comment: @jcorry I've edited that. I have a second doubt at the output of datetimepicker though. would you help me to post as a text it somehow to double check?

Comment: Are you submitting the form with method="GET"? The form data will be in the $_POST array if the method = "POST".

Comment: @jcorry yes the main form is using GET method

Comment: @jcorry now it works when I changed both methods to POST. Thank you, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is to get a DOB, subtract that from the date of now and present the difference in years, right?

That seems like a problem for DateTime::diff

```
$dob = new DateTime($_GET['dob']); // we'll just assume this is a safe date value for now
$now = new DateTime();

$age = $dob->diff($now);

$ageInYears = $age->format('%Y');
```

Comment: Thanks, it returns 00 now no matter what the date I pick is.

Comment: @FMeshreky I see you updated your question. Try this answer but with `$_GET['datetimepicker']` instead. If you change the field name on the client (i.e. the HTML form), you must change it on the server too.

Comment: @ADyson yes I did changed it in the php as well and made sure that all variables connected but something is wrong with the math or the datetimepicker output