# Calculate age from date of birth which is in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

When a user registers on my site, their birth date is stored in a mysql database. I'm using the `DATE` datatype for birth date.

How do I calculate the users current age?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems are you having? Are you able to get the date from mysql? Are you able to convert it to a PHP date? Do you know how to calculate the age from the birthdate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776682/php-calculate-age

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk I see what you did there, but those links to Google search results have a tendency to point back to the original post before long.

Comment: @WesleyMurch It's just a matter of taking a few moments to see if the problem exists on the inter web.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk This very post is already the 14th result.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for a PHP solution this works:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$birthdate = new DateTime("1973-04-18");
$interval = $today->diff($birthdate);
echo $interval->format('%y years');
```

Comment: @octern

i dont know the whole sequence what to do first then then what after, So please anybody guide me through the whole procedure. How to put everything in a variable so that i echo that variable and i get my answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of many date functions in both MySQL and PHP. MySQL example:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'1980-02-04',NOW()) AS age
```

Further reading:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php