# Calculate age from given datetime stamp - PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a variable `$dob` which returns a date, in the following format: 1970-02-01 00:00:00

How can I use php to calculate the age of the person?

Comment: use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) then do math

Comment: You substract the current date to the person's date of birth.

Comment: Age at which point in time? The time when you asked the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP calculate age](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776682/php-calculate-age)

Answer (score 5):

Your question is explained in detail in the [PHP documentation,](http://www.php.net/manual/de/dateinterval.format.php) it bascially goes like this:

```
// create a datetime object for a given birthday
$birthday = new DateTime("2012-12-12");
// substract your timestamp from it
$diff = $birthday->diff($dob);

// output the difference in years
echo $diff->format('%Y');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<?php

$age = '1970-02-01 00:00:00';

echo (int)((time()-strtotime($age))/31536000);
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/ZwGqBtMy): 43, in years.

Comment: @bwoebi: Thanks, wasn't thinking right. The age of a person is a number, not some decimal :).

Comment: No problem :-) (mass editing of answers ongoing…^^)

Comment: Would not this code be vulnerable to floating point casting error?

Comment: @Malkocoglu maybe by one single second; but normally it shouldn't.

Comment: [`intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php), I would think the problem should be fixed at the time-stamp though.

Comment: @DaveChen you are talking of a 32 bit system…

Comment: If the `$dob` variable is really out of wack, returning `9223372036854775807` would mess up a x64 system as well.

Comment: So I have given a few of these a go, including this one and I get the following error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff()

Answer (score 0):

```
$dob = '1970-02-01 00:00:00';

$date = new DateTime($dob);
$diff = $date->diff(new DateTime);

echo $diff->format('%R%a days');
```

Basically stolen from here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Formatting options: https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a go but got this error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff() - what did I do wrong? I copied your code exactly, hadn't even substituted the hard coded date with my variable yet...

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
echo date_create('1970-02-01')->diff(date_create('today'))->y;
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/52960).

Answer (score -1):

i would try this

```
$user_dob = explode('-',$dob);
$current_year= date('Y');
$presons_age = $current_year - $user_dob[0];
```

This is an untested code but i feel u should get the logic.

Answer (score -1):

strtotime() will convert your date into a timestamp, then subject that from time() and the result is the age in seconds.

`$age_in_seconds = time() - strtotime('1970-02-01');`

To display the age in years (+- 1 day), then divide by the number of seconds in a year:

`echo "Age in whole years is " . floor($age_in_seconds / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25);`

Comment: Possible floating point problems again...