# Calculating age in php

Tags: php

I need to calculate age in php. 
I use this solution:

```
$birthdate = '1986-09-16';

$_age = floor( (strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) - strtotime($birthDate)) / 31556926);
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776682/php-calculate-age)

Everything works fine, but for example if

`$birthday = '1194-01-06'` or

`$birthday = '1900-01-01'`

result is always **44**.

if `$birthday = '1910-11-09'` everything is fine again and result is **103**. Why?

Note: I don't want to use diff() function, because of some issues.

EDIT:

Earlier i had problems with diff(), some

> Warning range()

showed during processing and after refreshing of website everything was fine again... i could not find solution to fix it and somewhere i read that using of diff() could cause it. So i tried other solution and it worked... until now.

Finally I used this solution:

```
$birthDate = from database in timestamp format...
$birth = new \DateTime($birthDate);
$now = new \DateTime;
$age = $now->diff($birth)->y;
```

and I randomly get

```
Warning 
range(): step exceeds the specified range
```

again.

Comment: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What are these 'issues' with `DateTime::diff()`?

Comment: Also `strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))` is a horrendously roundabout way to get `time()`.

Comment: Not sure what's going on but you better try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer limit issue, either:

1. Your OS doesn't handle negative timestamps
2. The maximum integer values for signed integers on a 32 bit system

[strtotime()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

The valid range of a timestamp is typically from **Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC** to **Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC**. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.)

Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps, therefore your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix epoch (**1 Jan 1970**).

Comment: strtotime works starting 1970-01-01

Comment: @DarkSide: Yes, and works backwards using negative integers.

Comment: @DarkSide think this is based on the manual: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (see under Changelog)

Comment: Yes, everything I know about PHP was taken from there :-)

Comment: i changed the wording, "based on" sounds better ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using `date` that is using `timestamp` that has a default value of `time()` that is based on EPOCH that started on January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT - it's 44 years since 1970.

More on this can be found in the PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you read `strtotime()` manual (https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?

*The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (**the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC**), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.*