# Get the age of a person, using their birth date

Tags: php

I'm building a small site and got stuck on something.
How do you get a persons age, using their birth date?

So this should be something like:

```
$age=curr_date - YEAR($birth_date)
```

I hope the question is clear enough.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776682/php-calculate-age

Comment: Your logic is incorrect. You can't calculate someone's age by comparing their birth year to the current year. You have to take the actual dates into account.

Answer (score 5):

Use `date` and `strtotime` for getting the age of a person from birthdate.

```
$birth_date = '1991-12-10';
echo $age= date("Y") - date("Y", strtotime($birth_date)); //25
```

Answer (score 3):

Following is the code for that:

```
$dob = new DateTime('2015-10-02');
$today = new DateTime;
$age = $today->diff($dob);
```

And you can echo out the age like this:

```
echo $age->format('%y Years, %m Months and %d Days');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
<?php
$from = new DateTime('1993-09-19');
$to   = new DateTime('today');
echo $from->diff($to)->y;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert your date in strtotime like this

```
$userDob  = '18/01/2000'; //Try to convert your date format like this
$userDob  =  strtotime($userDob);
$currDate =  time();
$dateDiff =  $currDate  - $userDob;
echo Date('y',$dateDiff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$birth_date` is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

You can do it in following way. First create **DateTime** object of BirthDate,

```
$date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($birth_date));
$bDObj=new DateTime($date);
$cDate=new DateTime();

$age=$cDate->format("Y")-$bDObj->format("Y");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateInterval Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)?

```
<?php
$date1=date_create("2013-01-01");
$date2=date_create("2013-02-10");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);

echo $diff->format("Total number of years: %y.");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

        // ASSUMING YOU HAVE THE DATE IN MYSQL FORMAT: Y-m-d
        $birthDate  = "1980-10-05";
        $today      = date("Y-m-d");

        $dateA      = new DateTime($today);
        $dateB      = new DateTime($birthDate);

        $dateDiff   = $dateA->diff($dateB);
        $age        = "{$dateDiff->y} Years, {$dateDiff->m} Months and {$dateDiff->d} Days";

        var_dump($age);     //<== DUMPS: '35 Years, 8 Months and 3 Days'
```