# How to calculate variable value in PHP

Tags: php

I am new to PHP.

I want to show user's Age in numbers on user profile page.

I am recording user's Birth year in the database with this variable'birth_year'

I am not recording entire date of birth in datetime format.. I am only recording year like 1991

So currently if I want to display user's country then I write something like below

```
   <?php echo $user[country]; ?>
```

And that display's name of the country

**Now similarly, I want to disply user's age.**

So I am writting something like below but its working

```
<?php echo date('y') - $user[birth_year] ; ?>
```

So what php code should I write to get value of (Birth Year - Current Year)

Comment: What are your error? Did you actually use `$user[country];`?

Comment: Your birth_year should be complete date of birth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP calculate age](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776682/php-calculate-age)

Comment: Honestly, you should be able to figure this out by yourself or google "php subtract numbers" or something. This is VERY basic stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by substract birthday date from current date.

**Example -**

```
  # object oriented
    $from = new DateTime('1970-02-01');
    $to   = new DateTime('today');
    echo $from->diff($to)->y;

    # procedural
    echo date_diff(date_create('1970-02-01'), date_create('today'))->y;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= date('y') - $birth_year  ?> //only one line needed
```

try this code in php bracket

Here date('y') will return you current year (2016) and $birth_year is already having year of birth (Ex: 1994) so answer would be age

Comment: I wrote   <?php echo = date('y') - $user[birth_year] ; ?> but not working

Comment: tried without = like this <?php echo date('y') - $user[birth_year] ; ?> but still not working :(