# How to show age in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to show an age from this code:

```
$dob =  $entrantInfo['dobYear'].'-'.$entrantInfo['dobMonth'].'-'.$entrantInfo['dobDay'];
$age = date_diff(date_create($dob), date_create('today'))->y;

echo $age;
```

but it's not working, tried different kind of tutorials but I'm still having trouble, what should I do?
Cheers

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If not, what is your output?

Comment: @jaze refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776682/php-calculate-age

Comment: [working perfectly fine](https://eval.in/738125)

Comment: [It works good i guess](https://eval.in/738124)

Comment: You should first debug whether your're getting data in your array keys or not.. the code you provided is completely fine..

Comment: it doesn't show an error which is weird for me but I tried below's answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Basic Example

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2011-03-12');
$date2 = new DateTime('2008-03-09');

$diff = $date2->diff($date1);

echo $diff->y;
```

---

### Your Example

```
$entrantInfo['dobYear'] = '2011';
$entrantInfo['dobMonth'] = '03';
$entrantInfo['dobDay'] = '12';

$dob =  $entrantInfo['dobYear'].'-'.$entrantInfo['dobMonth'].'-'.$entrantInfo['dobDay']; // Get dynamic date    

$date1 = new DateTime($dob);
$date2 = new DateTime(); // Get current date

$diff = $date2->diff($date1);

echo $diff->y;
```

Would you please try above code?

Comment: thank you, this one is working when I try my own set of codes and made dob instead of separate database, by the way, how would I use my dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear for the date1? Thank you, I think I need to study more about the ->y thing @purvik7373

Comment: @Jaze I think `$dob =  $entrantInfo['dobYear'].'-'.$entrantInfo['dobMonth'].'-'.$entrantInfo['dobDay'];` this one is correct. Please try this.

Comment: how should I make the $date2 as current time?

Comment: You can cut out several lines from the answer -- the bit with using `date()` to get `$curr_date` is redundant as the `DateTime()` class is perfectly capable to getting the current date for itself.